# Duplicate MySQL Record with AI ID Field

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to duplicate my MySQL record using the following function. It says I have an error in my SQL, which I cannot see. I added a few echo's at the bottom to help diagnose. Also, is there any easier way that naming each row individually? (row[$x])?

The function is basically reading whichever ID is posted to it, then writing it back into the DB as if the user was simply entering it themselves without pressing the duplicate button.

I have tried other code on stack and I thought I'd write one I actually understood so here it is!

**EDIT:** It seems that my second query is the problematic one as well.

Thank you!

```
function procDupRec(){

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['duplicate']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id=$id";

            $result = mysql_query($query);      

            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

            $category = $row[1];
            $dateEntered = $row[2];
            $account = $row[3];
            $firstName = $row[4];
            $lastName = $row[5];
            $company = $row[6];
            $titlePos = $row[7];
            $officeNum = $row[8];
            $phoneExt = $row[9];        
            $homeNum = $row[10];
            $mobileNum = $row[11];
            $pagerNum = $row[12];
            $faxNum = $row[13];
            $address1 = $row[14];
            $address2 = $row[15];
            $city = $row[16];
            $state = $row[17];
            $zip = $row[18];
            $email = $row[19];
            $website = $row[20];
            $notes = $row[21];  
            $editBit = $row[22];    
            $protection = $row[23];
            $lastIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            }

            $query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (category, dateEntered, account, firstName, lastName, company, titlePos, officeNum, phoneExt, homeNum, mobileNum, pagerNum, faxNum, address1, address2, city, state, zip, email, website, notes, editBit, protection, lastIP) VALUES ('$category', '$dateEntered', '$account', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$company', '$titlePos', '$officeNum', '$phoneExt', '$homeNum', '$mobileNum', '$pagerNum', '$faxNum', '$address1', '$address2', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$website', '$notes', '$editBit', '$protection', '$lastIP')");

            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);

            echo $query2;

            echo mysql_error();



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Echoing a query will not work after you executed the query. That will only contain a result.

You should store the query before executing it, like this

```
$query2 ="INSERT INTO contacts (category, dateEntered, account, firstName, lastName, company, titlePos, officeNum, phoneExt, homeNum, mobileNum, pagerNum, faxNum, address1, address2, city, state, zip, email, website, notes, editBit, protection, lastIP) VALUES ('$category', '$dateEntered', '$account', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$company', '$titlePos', '$officeNum', '$phoneExt', '$homeNum', '$mobileNum', '$pagerNum', '$faxNum', '$address1', '$address2', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$website', '$notes', '$editBit', '$protection', '$lastIP')";
mysql_query($query2);
```

With this you can examine the query with `echo $query2`

Another option to duplicate:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO contacts 
                    (category, dateEntered, account, firstName, lastName, company, titlePos, officeNum, phoneExt, homeNum, mobileNum, pagerNum, faxNum, address1, address2, city, state, zip, email, website, notes, editBit, protection, lastIP) 

                    (SELECT category, dateEntered, account, firstName, lastName, company, titlePos, officeNum, phoneExt, homeNum, mobileNum, pagerNum, faxNum, address1, address2, city, state, zip, email, website, notes, editBit, protection, lastIP FROM contacts WHERE id=$id)" 
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Then I get a "Duplicate entry '2852' for key 1"

Comment: is auto_increment on for the ID row? Because if it is, then the ID field should be ignored

Comment: Primary Key, Auto Incremement, and Not Null is on for ID field

Comment: I changed the query to add the columns all separately